# how insert data into clickhouse table with permission denied?

Tags: python, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

Got error while inserting date into Clickhouse table:

clickhouse_connect.driver.exceptions.DatabaseError: :HTTPDriver for http://localhost:8123 returned response code 500)
std::exception. Code: 1001, type: std::__1::__fs::filesystem::filesystem_error, e.what() = filesystem error: in rename: Permission denied ["./store/c67/c6760d86-380d-4d9a-806d-dc5b13398ca3/tmp_insert_all_1_1_0/"] ["./store/c67/c6760d86-380d-4d9a-806d-dc5b13398ca3/all_1_1_0/"]
Cannot print extra info for Poco::Exception (version 23.7.3.14 (official build))

Comment: how do you install clickhouse-server? is this the docker or standalone?

Comment: could you share `df -h /var/lib/clickhouse` ?

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc        251G  176G   64G  74% /

Comment: clickhouse is installed in wsl

Comment: Is clickhouse-server installed as docker inside wsl? 
share `sudo mount -l | grep /dev/sdc` and `grep -C 10 path /var/lib/clickhouse/preprocessed_configs/config.xml`